# Problema na lib PyVCF - Extrair dados de arquivos vcf

Tags: python

recebo o erro ao tentar ler um arquivo vcf, nao encontrei solução ou outra lib para lidar com arquivos vcf, alguma sugestão? tentei com as duas versoes do python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./csvBasic.py", line 6, in <module>
    record = next(vcf_reader)
  File "/home/yan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vcf/parser.py", line 551, in next
    pos = int(row[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**scikit-allel**](https://scikit-allel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)
>   "Este pacote fornece utilitários para análise exploratória de dados de variação genética em larga escala. Ele é baseado em bibliotecas científicas Python numpy, scipy e outras de propósito geral."

```
$ pip install scikit-allel
```

Vamos considerar o arquivo `sample.vcf` com o seguinte conteudo:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.3
##reference=file:///seq/references/1000GenomesPilot-NCBI36.fasta
##contig=<ID=20,length=62435964,assembly=B36,md5=f126cdf8a6e0c7f379d618ff66beb2da,species="Homo sapiens",taxonomy=x>
##INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total Depth">
##INFO=<ID=AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Allele Frequency">
##INFO=<ID=DB,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="dbSNP membership, build 129">
##FILTER=<ID=q10,Description="Quality below 10">
##FILTER=<ID=s50,Description="Less than 50% of samples have data">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Read Depth">
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  NA00001 NA00002 NA00003
20      14370   rs6054257       G       A       29      PASS    DP=14;AF=0.5;DB GT:DP   0/0:1   0/1:8   1/1:5
20      17330   .       T       A       3       q10     DP=11;AF=0.017  GT:DP   0/0:3   0/1:5   0/0:41
20      1110696 rs6040355       A       G,T     67      PASS    DP=10;AF=0.333,0.667;DB GT:DP   0/2:6   1/2:0   2/2:4
20      1230237 .       T       .       47      PASS    DP=13   GT:DP   0/0:7   0/0:4   ./.:.
20      1234567 microsat1       GTC     G,GTCT  50      PASS    DP=9    GT:DP   0/1:4   0/2:2   1/1:3
```

Abaixo 2 exemplos de extração de dados do arquivo, no primeiro vamos utilizar a função [read_vcf()](https://scikit-allel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/io.html#allel.read_vcf) para extrair os dados para arrays do tipo numpy:

callset = allel.read_vcf('sample.vcf')
print(callset.keys())

Saida:

```
dict_keys(['samples', 'calldata/GT', 'variants/ALT', 'variants/CHROM', 'variants/FILTER_PASS', 'variants/ID', 'variants/POS', 'variants/QUAL', 'variants/REF'])
```

No segundo exemplo vamos utilizar a função `vcf_to_dataframe()` para ler o arquivo e atribuir a um `pandas DataFrame`:

```
df = allel.vcf_to_dataframe('sample.vcf')
print(df)
```

Saida:

```
    CHROM      POS         ID   REF ALT_1   ALT_2   ALT_3   QUAL  FILTER_PASS
0      20     14370 rs6054257     G     A     NaN     NaN   29.0         True
1      20     17330         .     T     A     NaN     NaN    3.0        False
2      20   1110696 rs6040355     A     G       T     NaN   67.0         True
3      20   1230237         .     T   NaN     NaN     NaN   47.0         True
4      20   1234567 microsat1   GTC     G    GTCT     NaN   50.0         True
```

[Veja mais nesse excelente post](http://alimanfoo.github.io/2017/06/14/read-vcf.html).

Comment: o arquivo que estou tentando ler é minha agenda de contatos que exportei do google em um arquivo chamado contacts.vcf e recebo o seguinte erro:  Theaders = _read_vcf_headers(stream)
  File "/home/yan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allel/io/vcf_read.py", line 1772, in _read_vcf_headers
    raise RuntimeError('VCF file is missing mandatory header line ("#CHROM...")')
RuntimeError: VCF file is missing mandatory header line ("#CHROM...")

Comment: Esta tentando com a lib que eu sugeri?

Comment: Vc disse que os dados são da agenda de contatos do google, nesse caso, se não me engano o vcf é um outro tipo de arquivo (ios), mas não seria mais simples vc exportar como CSV?

Comment: exportei em csv e consegui tratar os dados, muito obrigado